# Как сохранить файл из инпута в папку в проекте React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, файлы

Я разрабатывал интернет-магазин, как пет-проект и сохранял картинки блюд прямо в базу, но тут есть проблема в том, что потом, скажем, 30 блюд с их картинками из базы получаются слишком долго, около минуты. Теперь я хочу это изменить. Как мне получить картинку из `<input type="file"/>`, сохранить ее в папку react-проекта. А в базе я буду хранить только название изображения и отображать его. Подскажите, возможно ли вообще такое реализовать?

Comment: По хорошему, картинки должны храниться на сервере в какой то директории. Вы же сейчас, как я понимаю, картинки серверу отправляете, что бы он в БД их положил? У вас на чем написан бэк?

Comment: Да, это фулл стек проект, бек написан на спринге(Java), но во-первых я не знаю, можно ли в спринге сохранить картинку тоже в папку проекта, во-вторых какой смысл, если это пет-проект, а не какой-то реальный коммерческий проект, и попроизводительнее будет сразу хранить в проекте на реакте.

Comment: @MatveyAndrosyuk пиши бэк на nodejs+mongo , быстрее выйдет и хранить файлы сможешь прям рядышком

Comment: да нее, я же ищу работу на позицию Java-разработчик, + хочу показать знания React, так как это большой плюс, и мне нужно использовать мои языки

Comment: @MatveyAndrosyuk Тогда точно надо решать задачу правильно и разбираться с java, как сохранять файл. Силами React это точно не решить.

Comment: То есть в js/react никак нельзя сохранить файл в папку проекта?